# HQL error in the select clause

Tags: hql

When I used a SQL query in Hibernate (HQL) I got following error:

```
student is not mapped. [select stud.vStudentName from student as stud]
```

Here  is table name in MySQL and following is function of the select query.

```
public static void querySubject(Session session) 
{
    String sql_query="select stud.vStudentName from student as stud";
    Query query1=session.createQuery(sql_query);

    for(Iterator it=query1.iterate();it.hasNext();) 
    {
        Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
        System.out.println("Subject Name:"+row[0]);
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Check your .cfg file and use same name in select query.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an HQL problem, unless your class is actually named Student for example - HQL is case sensitive. More likely it is a mapping problem. Check if you able to use your student class via the Session.get method. If so, it is just that you haven't mapped this properly.

Comment: yes I can use my student class via session.get. so what can be the mapping problem? and how to solve it?

Comment: In that case, it could be case sensitivity as I said. Is your class Student or student?

Answer (score 0):

In HQL Java classes are case sensitive, therefore try

```
String sql_query="select stud.vStudentName from Student as stud";
```

Answer (score 0):

HQL is not SQL. It's something that *maps* to SQL. The names you should use in HQL are *not* the names of table and columns in the database. The names you should use in HQL are the names of the *classes* and *properties* in the Java codebase.

So, unless your Java class is also called "student" you should change "student" to the actual name of your Java class that is mapped to the "student" table.

(If you wanted to be able to use literal SQL, I think createSQLQuery is the method you were looking for. You probably didn't though -- there isn't a need to use SQL for something this simple, and you may as well stick with something that maps more closely to your Java code)